# UiPath PDF activities

Tags: uipath

I am trying to read a PDF as text, and I can write it back with junk in it, which is fine as I have a parser component to get the bits I need.

My question is how can I read specific parts of the PDF and ignore the rest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your PDF is well formatted, you can do it using text scraping, but that means you need to open the PDF file and it must be visible for Native Scraping to work

Comment: This works with Adobe Reader DC only if you have the right settings. Each time you open it again you have to open the settingsdialog. (Settings could be correct but it does not take them without opening the dialog)